# Filter products by options

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have following database structure to store product options.

[image: DB]

Now i have problem to filter out products that match only given options. First i did WHERE option_id IN (array of options), but that would give me products that match any of the options and that is not solution. User wants to filter out only products with given material, color, and size for instance. And if i do WHERE option_id = 4 AND option_id = 6 for instance i get nothing.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS id,
                ...
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON p.id = pi.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1
  AND po.option_id = 1 // only to get the idea
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,
      12
```

Just to mention it is PHP application , where user select options from select element with or without multiple attribute.

How to acomplish this?

Comment: What columns shall your result list contain? Only columns of table `products`?

Comment: No, also images. I do GROUP_CONCAT from produt images and then separate them in output or presenter class. And also some full text relevance if phrase search is entered.

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is superfluous. You group by ID and select the ID, so there can be no duplicates that need be removed.

Comment: The ERM you are showing seems incomplete. Is there also an `option` table containing all possible options you can link a product to via `product_options`? What is a feature? Can you give an example? It's strange to see four tables in the ERM, four tables in the query, but only two intersect.

Comment: No there isn't aditional tables. Right now i have it implemented like this. 
Feature is for instance color. Feature options for color are for instance red, white, blue. In backend of application i display select for each feature with it's options, where values are option ids. When form is submited selected option ids are saved in product_options table like product_id, option_id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `having`:

```
SELECT p.id AS id,  ...
FROM products p JOIN
     product_categories pc
     ON p.id = pc.product_id LEFT JOIN
     product_images pi
     ON p.id = pi.product_id JOIN
     product_options po
     ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1 AND
      po.option_id IN (4, 6)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 2
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 12;
```

The `HAVING` clause is specifying that a given `id` has two matching options.  Because of the `WHERE` clause, these are the only two options that you care about.

I didn't change your approach (you didn't supply the complete query), but you are doing joins along different dimensions -- categories, images, and options.  This creates a Cartesian product for each product, and that is often not the best approach to such a query.

Comment: OK can you tell me how to improve it? Also how to SELECT products that have as i said, selected color, size and material for instance?

Comment: What does this line do? 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 2

Comment: @cvetan: From your description and query it seems that an option is a type plus value, e.g. option_id 1 = color:yellow, option_id 2 = size:XL. Gordon selects two such options (option_id 4 and 6) and uses `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 2` to only get products that have the full count of desired options, two in the example.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can i avoid cartesian product if i want to include products that have no categories, images, options? If i use INNER JOIN i will not get all products, that not have this criteria.

Comment: The Cartesian product is not related to the inner versus outer join -- both cause it.  You can ask another question if  you want to remove the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `LEFT JOIN` in the solution.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS id
FROM products p
JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1
      AND po.option_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(po.option_id) = 3
```

My solution keep only tables necessary to find the products with specified options.

In the case you want products having exactly this options and no others you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS id
FROM products p
JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1 AND 
      po.option_id IN (1, 2, 3) and
      NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM product_options po2
        WHERE p.id = po2.product_id and po2.option_id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
      )
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(po.option_id) = 3
```

If you want to select products accoding to the other conditions (like product categories and so on) then use `IN` in the `WHERE` clause. This approach avoids generating duplicate `po.option_id` and the outer query will still work correctly even without `DISTINCT` in `COUNT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS id
FROM products p
JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1 AND 
      po.option_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND
      -- use the following IN predicate to select products with specific features without introducing duplicates in your query
      p.id IN (
         select product_id FROM product_categories WHERE <your_condition>
      )
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(po.option_id) = 3
```

Comment: Yes i need it initially to display products that are not having options at all.

Comment: No list is not final. You can dinamically add product features, and add them to product. For instance size: L, M, XL. Color: red and blue. Material: cotton.

Comment: If i understand your query right HAVING clause indicates chosen options right? SO here is only one option selected?

Comment: @cvetan it was a mistake, I was missing `COUNT`. Right now, it is checking for all three options. The product is returned only when it has all three options. The second query return products having exactly those options (and no others). the third query allow you to add some other conditions on products you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

You select products with image lists. Something like:

```
select products.*, group_concat(product_images.id)
```

Additionally there may be options the product must all meet. This is criteria that belongs in the `WHERE` clause.

```
select
  p.*,
  (select group_concat(image) from product_images i where i.product_id = p.id) as images
from products p
where product_active = 1
and id in
(
  select product_id
  from product_options
  where option_id in (1,3,55,97)
  group by product_id
  having count(*) = 4 -- four options in this example
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i've managed to return exactly what i wanted.

Now i just have problem with pagination query for the filtered products.

Final search query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id AS id,
                main_price,
                promotion_price,
                NEW,
                sale,
                recommended,
                COUNT(pi.filename) AS image_count,
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pi.filename
                             ORDER BY pi.main_image DESC, pi.id ASC) AS images,
                name_sr,
                uri_sr,
                description_sr
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON p.id = pi.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1
  AND po.option_id IN(1)
  AND p.main_price BETWEEN 5250.00 AND 14000.00
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 1
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,
      12
```

Pagination query is something like this i modified it accorgin to new filter query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS number
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON p.id = pi.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1
  AND po.option_id IN(1)
  AND p.main_price BETWEEN 5250.00 AND 14000.00
GROUP BY(p.id)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 1
```

If i leave out DISTINCT in SELECT COUNT i don't get filtered pagination, if i set DISTINCT i get number of rows that corespond to pagination. I suppose i could add another count(*) to all of this with subquery, but not sure if that is way to go and if there is more efficient and elegant way to do this.

Comment: `DISTINCT` in the upper query is still superfluous as already explained. Then please always use column qualifiers when working with multiple tables. What tables do main_price, promotion_price , NEW, sale, recommended, etc. reside in? What do you select product_categories for?

Comment: Anyway: this is no answer. If you have another question, ask it in a new request.

Comment: If i don't use DISTINCT i get rows multiplied with rows in product_options table. I've tried without it, it returned real results multiplied with it.

Comment: Then something is very wrong with the query. You group by `id`. I suppose that is meant to be `p.id`? Can it be that another table has a column `id` in the DBMS picks that instead? If it is `p.id` you group by and you select `p.id`, then there can be no duplicate rows, because every row will have a unique `p.id`. `DISTINCT` will be superfluous.

Comment: Besides the query is flawed. At least you multiply your image count with the number of options x categories. Aggregate before joining.

Comment: If i use this: 
`SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS number FROM products p LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON p.id = pi.product_id LEFT JOIN product_options ON p.id = po.product_id WHERE p.product_active = 1 AND po.option_id IN (1,7,9) AND p.main_price BETWEEN x AND y GROUP BY (p.id) HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 3` 
I get 60. If i use `DISTINCT` in select i get one if there is only one product matching. If i get two, i get two rows with one. What is wrong?

Comment: I select product categories because filter can accept categories also. So i have filter method that accepts parameter list. And it works for multiple possible conditions supplied. Look at this query:
`SELECT COUNT(p.d)
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1
AND po.option_id IN (1)
AND p.main_price BETWEEN 52500.00 AND 14000.00
GROUP BY (p.id)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 1`
I get 37 rows with value of 1. What is flawwed here? I removed unneded joins for count query.

Comment: I added another question regarding this query. Thanks.