# Pagination count query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I had this question about filtering different products by selecting options. That query has been solved here: [Filter products by options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46973292/filter-products-by-options).

My problem is now with the count query for the pagination. For instance this query returns 37 rows with the count of 1.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS number
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON p.id = pi.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1
  AND po.option_id IN(1)
  AND p.main_price BETWEEN 5250.00 AND 14000.00
GROUP BY(p.id)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 1
```

But if i remove DISTINCT:

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS number
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON p.id = pi.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1
  AND po.option_id IN(1)
  AND p.main_price BETWEEN 5250.00 AND 14000.00
GROUP BY(p.id)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 1
```

this returns also 37 rows with mixed numbers.

What am doing wrong? I know i could outcome this by running aditional count on this result set but i think that is not right solution?

Also as suggested in previous question, there was stated that i should not be needing DISTINCT and the query is flawwed because of that. Can you tell me what is the problem?

Comment: what is your question?. If you use `GROUP BY(p.id) ` , it will return 37 rows as there are 37 distinct `p.id`s . and all these ids have only one `option_id` what is confusing in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys it is more clear now. Is something like this good enough to solve this?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS number
FROM (SELECT p.id
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_images pi ON p.id = pi.product_id
LEFT JOIN product_options po ON p.id = po.product_id
WHERE p.product_active = 1
  AND po.option_id IN(1)
  AND p.main_price BETWEEN 5250.00 AND 14000.00
GROUP BY(p.id)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT po.option_id) = 1) AS count_table
```

I will go with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference in your queries is here:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS number
```

vs.

```
SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS number
```

So you get the same number of result rows, because `FROM`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` are all the same. Only the data per row you select is different.

In the first case it's the number of distinct IDs that are not null, which is always 1, because you group by that ID. (You say: Look at all records with ID 5 and count how many different IDs you find in these records. Well, the ID in every record with ID 5 is 5. So it's only one ID.)

In the second case you count IDs that are not null. As the ID is never null, this is the same as counting records: `COUNT(*)`. And you'd better make this clear by using `COUNT(*)` instead of the obfuscated `COUNT(p.id)`.